# Does this set contain an infinite number of prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I know that it still is not known whether the sequence $n^2+1$ contain an infinite number of prime numbers.

I guess that this is also not known for any sequence of the form $n^k+1$ where $k\geq2$ is an even natural number.

But what if we look at all these sequences together and then raise a question does the set of their values contain an infinite number of prime numbers?

What exactly do I mean by this? Well, let us define the set $P$ as $P=\bigcup_{i=2}^{\infty} \{n^i+1:n\in\mathbb N\}$.

> Does $P$ contain an infinite number of prime numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is equivalent to the first question. In fact, if $k$ is odd, then
$n^k + 1$ is not prime, except for $n=1$. If $k$ is even, then $n^k$ is a square, so you can write it as $(n^s)^2+1$.

Comment: it's not equiVALENT

Comment: why not? Could you explain?

Comment: I think you needed to say if $k$ has an odd prime factor then $n^k+1$  is not prime.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Exodd's claim is true, though, and sufficient: suppose $\{n^i+1: i, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ contains infinitely many primes. Then (by Exodd's claim) all but finitely many of those are of the form $n^{2j}+1$, hence of the form $(n^j)^2+1=m^2+1$. While what you say is true, it's not relevant.

Comment: Oh ok, I see, thank you, my mistake.